# Does a plane have to be spanned by two vectors that are perpendicular?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I'm beginning to learn some vector calculus, and I am slightly confused about the textbook's explanation of planes spanned by two vectors.

They said for example that the *xy* plane is an example of the plane ***spanned by***  **i** and **j**. This concept makes sense to me, but I'm just wondering if a plane needs to necessarily be defined by two vectors perpendicular to each other like the *xy* , *yz* , and *xz* planes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ also span the $xy$ plane. You only need two independent vectors to span the plane.

Answer (score 1):

The two vectors need not be perpendicular, but they are not allowed to be parallel to (i.e., scalar multiples of) each other in order to span a plane. For example, the vectors $(1, 0)$ and $(2, 1)$ span the $xy$ plane, but the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(2,0)$ do not.

The key idea is whether you can reach every point in the plane by forming a [linear combination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_combination), $a_{1}v_{1} + a_{2}v_{2}$, of your two vectors, where $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ are scalars (i.e., real numbers, in the context of this question). Note that the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(2,0)$ do span a horizontal *line* through the origin, but you could achieve the same result with just one of these vectors: the other is redundant for this purpose.

(See also the concept of [linear independence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence). You could well meet it very soon in your multivariable/vector calculus course or in a linear algebra course.)